# Compass Foundation with Prepros error

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass, prepros

I can't seem to find an answer as to why I get this error when I compile my sass file with Prepros. I'm using Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris). Sass: 3.4.15 (selective Steve). Foundation: 5.5.2

Any thoughts?

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.
          Load paths:
            C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Test-1/scss
            C:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/gems/gems/bourbon-4.0.2/app/assets/stylesheets
            C:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/gems/gems/neat-1.6.0/app/assets/stylesheets
            C:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/gems/gems/bitters-0.10.0/app/assets/stylesheets
            C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Test-1/scss/sass
            C:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/gems/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets
            Compass::SpriteImporter
    on line 58 of _settings.scss
    from line 1 of app.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.

C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Test-1\scss\app.scss
```

My config.rb file:

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Comment: What does your config.rb look like?

Comment: I added the config.rb file to the main question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the path to your foundation directory (via add_import_path) is correct?  It doesn't even look like Compass is searching the specified directory (even if I reference a directory that doesn't exist, Compass still informs me that it looked there anyway in the Load paths part of the error).

Comment: What versions of Compass/Sass/Foundation are you using?

Comment: Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris).  Sass: 3.4.15 (selective Steve).  Foundation: 5.5.2

Comment: Did you try uninstalling Compass and reinstalling it?

Comment: I get a similar error when editing with Sublime Text. If I'm editing an import and try to save it I get a similar error. Bizarrely this doesn't happen when I use brackets to edit the file.